# To redraw the surfaceview to move to the next level

Tags: android

I have `class Maingamepannel`  extending `surfaceview` for my games first level everything works fine. Now i Want to redraw my `surfaceview` for my next level so that I can reinitialize my
bitmap objects at their initial position and start the game again with bit diffrent conditions
which i have handeled in switch case.

To achieve this after finishing my annimations in first loop I have called my activity showing view again like this---

```
Intent backIntent = new Intent(getContext(),mygame.pkg.StartGame.class);    
sg.level++;     
backIntent.putExtra("levelkey",""+sg.level);
getContext().startActivity(backIntent);
```

By doing this I am able to redraw my bitmaps at initial position and starting annimations again, But the problem is this is drawing a another surface while my requirement is to use the same surface
or delete the first surface and then drawing a another one.

Comment: You are calling startActivity. So why are you surprized that you have new Activity -> new SurfaceView?

Comment: Yes I am calling the new activity but I want to finish the first view that is not happening here.Is there any way to delete the first one or clear the view before reinitializing?

Comment: To moving to the next level in game was easy task and i achieved it by just level counter and simple switch case in Game loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To moving to the next level in game was easy task and i achieved it by just level counter and simple switch case in Game loop